# Нюансы работы с retrofit'ом

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Может кто то объяснить примерную структуру retrofit'a?
Что я имею в виду, делаю задание по примеру, поэтому есть трудности

- Написал интерфейс в котором обратился к адресу
- Написал модель
- Написал адаптер и подготовил recyclerView(ну более менее)
- Есть даже сам класс запроса(код представлен ниже)

Так понимаю осталось настроить сам retrofit, то есть проинициилизировать его куда мы подставляем сам конвертер, основную часть ссылки, что то вроде этого

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("какая то ссылка")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

и уже ниже него в моей активити еще дополнительно добавить onFailure/onSucces?
Что я пропустил и возможно кто то сможет внятно объяснить принцип, можно даже ресурсом, потому что то что я читаю из офф [документации](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body) не совсем мне понятно(примера адекватного не дают)

Сам запрос:

```
class Repo{
    Methods api;

    public Observable<List<Model>> getAllTop(){
        return api.getTopStories()
                .switchMap(new Func1<Response<List<Integer>>, Observable<? extends List<Model>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<? extends List<Model>> call(Response<List<Integer>> listResponse) {
                        if (listResponse.isSuccessful())
                        return Observable.from(listResponse.body())
                                .flatMap(integer ->  api.getTopStore(integer)
                                .switchMap(new Func1<Response<Model>, Observable<Model>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Observable<Model> call(Response<Model> modelResponse) {
                                        if (modelResponse.isSuccessful())
                                        return Observable.just(modelResponse.body());
                                        else
                                            return Observable.error(new Throwable(modelResponse.message()));
                                    }
                                })).toList();
                        else
                            return Observable.error(new Throwable(listResponse.message()));
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Теперь ван нужно создать объект этого интерфейса вот так:

```
HttpApi httpApi = retrofit.create(HttpApi.class);
```

HttpApi - это интерфейс с апи. Запросы можно делать вот так:

```
Call<Object> result = httpApi.getData();
    result.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
           //успешно выполнен запрос
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
            //ошибка 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ага, примерно начинаю понимать. А в сам `onResponse`  прописываем само получение этого с сервера? + у меня есть запрос, как и где к нему можно правильно обратиться?(обновил вопрос)

Comment: + разве не надо дополнительно инициилизировать okhttpclient?

Comment: Не обязательно. Если хотите перехватывать запросы либо сделать кеш то для этого нужно еще okhttp подключать